# How can I update EWMA(exponential weighted moving average) in O(1) when an element is added?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

The parameterization of ewma is defined here(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average).
Calculation of ewma for a given vector is quite simple. But, if alpha is equal to 2 / (n + 1), where n is the number of the elements in the vector, how can I update ewma in O(1)(constant time complexity) when a new element is added to the vector?(Of course, no elements are removed when the new element is added.)
It would be easy if alpha is a constant, but I have to renew alpha from 2 / (n + 1) to 2 / (n + 2).
If the problem is about sma(simple moving average), I can update it in O(1) by
sma = (sma * n + new_element) / (n + 1). But, I'm struggling with the case of ewma.
The answer doesn't have to be perfect. I mean, approximation is allowed. Please help me if you have any ideas on how to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: this question is about maths not about code, better try here: https://math.stackexchange.com/. Please dont spam unrelated tags

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs to another SE site, like maths.SE.

Comment: I took only a cursory glance but I highly doubt a O(1) runtime is achievable. I have some reason to believe even an approximation is impossible in this case.